# My contract level metadata is not showing on Opensea!

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, polygon

I need some help I'm new to solidity and I'm reading the docs for opensea, but I must be missing something. I have an ERC721 contract on Polygon, but the contract level metadata won't show. I'm following the instructions (bottom of page) here: https://docs.opensea.io/docs/contract-level-metadata
and this is my contract: deployed from Remix IDE!

```
contract OrdoLoroPublic is ERC721, Ownable {
    uint256 private _nextTokenId;

    constructor(address initialOwner)
        ERC721("Ordo Loro Public", "LOORP")
        Ownable(initialOwner)
    {}

      event ContractURIUpdated(string);
     
      mapping(uint256 => Attr) public attributes;

    struct Attr {
        string nftname;
        string describe;  
        string svg;
        string Interactive;
    }

    function namedescribe(
        string memory _nftname,
        string memory _describe,
        string memory _svg,
        string memory _Interactive
    ) public 
    {   
        uint256 tokenId;
        attributes[tokenId] = Attr(_nftname, _describe, _svg, _Interactive);
        
    }

   

    //Just press space in the text section if you don't want text.
    function findSvg() public view returns(string memory){
     uint256 tokenId;
       
        return attributes[tokenId].svg;
    } 
    
    mapping(string => string) public URI;
    function setcontractURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        
        returns (string memory)
    {   string memory you = string(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender));
        string memory urlx =  string.concat("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,",attributes[tokenId].svg);
        string memory describe1 = string(abi.encodePacked("Interactive On Chain Ordo Loro (LOOR) ", attributes[tokenId].describe, tokenId));
        string memory json = string.concat('{"name": "', attributes[tokenId].nftname, '",', '"external_url": "',urlx,'",', '"description": "',describe1,'",', '"animation_url": "',urlx,'",', '"fees": [{ "fee": "7","recipient": "',you,'","required": "true"},', '{ "fee": "3","recipient": "0x4E0988B00A3AEBA05f69c94BC76fCc1cE3f26f5B","required": "true"}],', '"attributes": [{"trait_type": "Blockchain", "value": "True"},', '{"trait_type": "On Chain", "value": "True"},', '{"trait_type": "Interactive", "value": "',attributes[tokenId].Interactive,'"},', '{"trait_type": "SVG", "value": "',attributes[tokenId].svg,'"}]} ');
        
       
        string memory _contractURI = string.concat("data:application/json;utf8,", json);
        URI["URI"] = _contractURI;
        return URI["URI"];
    }

    // function ContractURIUpdate() public {
    //     emit ContractURIUpdated();
      
    // }
    
    function contractURI() public view override returns (string memory) {
    
        return URI["URI"];
    }
     
    // mapping(uint256 =>  string) public URI2;

    // function settokenURI(uint256 tokenId)public {
    //     URI2[tokenId] = URI["URI"];
    // }
    // // function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view  returns (string memory) {
    
    //     return URI2[tokenId] ;
    // }
  

     function safeMint()
        public
        
    {   emit ContractURIUpdated(URI["URI"]);
        uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
        
        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId );
       
        
    }
}
```

https://polygonscan.com/address/0x392b4908F5715f21d4138F63C4A3345003628066#code . I start with Openzepplin imports erc721 and ownable
Please help if you know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi! Could you post the contract code directly here? It'll help people be able to read it more easily. You don't need to include the entire flattened output, just the code from the main NFT contract. You may also want to include your deploy script - that might help reveal if there was an issue setting the metadata during deployment.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know to paste the code!

Comment: the `tokenURI` function is commented out in the code before - isn't that how OS reads metadata?